# Spring Data Neo4J @Query

Tags: java, spring, neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

I have two NodeEntities: Speaker and Talks.
Speaker has Set
Now I'm creating SpeakerRepository extends GraphRepository and everything is working.
But I'm not succeeding to create Query for fetching all Speakers which has talks with titles, which contains specific words.
For example I want to get all speakers which talks about spring.
The method would be: Set findAllSpeakerWithTalksLike(String partOfTalkTitle)
Can you please explain what should be the content of @Query annotation above this method

Answer (score 0):

Try this one, assuming your `Talk` has a `title` property and the `Speaker` has a `talks` related-to collection.

```
  Set<Speaker> findAllSpeakerWithTalksTitleContaining(String partOfTalkTitle)
```

the cypher query would be, it won't be very fast on large datasets b/c there is no index supporting it.

```
MATCH (t:Talk)<-[:TALK]-(s:Speaker) WHERE t.title = ".*partOfTalkTitle.*"
RETURN s
```

You could annotate `@Indexed(type=FULLTEXT) String title;`  then it would use a legacy lucene fulltext index for the search.

Comment: I tried this and ... Error executing statement MATCH (t:Talk)<-[:TALK]-(s:Speaker) WHERE t.title = .*partOfTalkTitle.* RETURN s
Invalid input '*': expected Digits (line 1, column 54)
"MATCH (t:Talk)<-[:TALK]-(s:Speaker) WHERE t.title = .*partOfTalkTitle.* RETURN s"